# How do I set up a UITableView element within a UIViewController with other UI elements?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am using Storyboards. I have a UI ViewController and within it, I have a bunch of labels and buttons before the UITableView.

I know how to do it using UITableViewControllers, which have the datasource protocols built in with them. How do I implement the same using a UIViewController with UITableView? Do I use IBOutlets to access the UITableView? How do I populate it from there?

Comment: Question is a bit unclear here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of the methods is the same as it would be in a UITableViewController.

The only difference is that if you are adding a table view manually, you need to connect the datasource and delegate outlets yourself (and declare that you implement the protocols). This is done for you if you use UITableViewController, but that comes with the price of not being able to add other views.

In the .h file of your view controller subclass, declare that you implement the protocols:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource>
```

In storyboard, select the table view, open the outlets inspector, drag from the delegate and datasource outlets to your view controller object.

Comment: How exactly do I connect the datasource and delegate outlets (and declare that I implement the protocols)?